# FileNotFound exception when attempting to run an XNA F# project

Tags: f#, xna, filenotfoundexception

I managed to cobble together a suitable implementation of a sample game in F# with xna. However when i try to instantiate my derived game class, the code throws a FileNotFound exception trying to access the Microsoft.Xna.Framework assembly. Why does this happen?

Code:

```
#light
open System
open Microsoft.Xna.Framework
open Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio
open Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content
open Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Design
open Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices
open Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics
open Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input

type SampleGame() as self =
    class
    inherit Game()
    let mutable manager : GraphicsDeviceManager = null
    let mutable spriteBatch : SpriteBatch = null
    do
        manager <- new GraphicsDeviceManager(self)
    override Game.Initialize() = 
        base.Initialize()
    override Game.LoadContent() = 
        spriteBatch <- new SpriteBatch(manager.GraphicsDevice)
        base.LoadContent()
    override Game.Update(gameTime) = 
        base.Update(gameTime)
        if GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back = ButtonState.Pressed then
            self.Exit()
    override Game.Draw(gameTime) = 
        manager.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        base.Draw(gameTime)
    end

let game = new SampleGame()
game.Run()
```

I have added the proper references by the way.
Edit: after some exploration, i found that my F# project is being compiled to 64 bit, which does not work with the 32 bit XNA dlls. However VS 2010 doesnt let me change the solution platform. How do i fix this?

Comment: @RCIX - Your effort with F# is cool and all, but you know, the looks of this sample really reminds me of why picking the right tool for the job is so important.

Comment: You're probably right but i was just getting it working to mess around since its the only thinkg i could think of that would be a decent project for learing about classes. If i build anything it will just be a small game. After all, the best way to learn about something is to try to apply it to something and see what sticks, is it not?

Comment: I totally agree whit that. I'm reading up on F# currently and it just struck me when seeing your sample that some things are better done with an imperative language, and seeing that F# really shines when it comes to the functional stuff like calculations and data manipulation. And again, the great thing about .Net is that you can mix and match languages depending on what you're creating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough about XNA, but is it 'in the GAC', or do you need to copy the XNA dlls next to your .exe?  It sounds like perhaps having Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll next to your .exe may solve it.

EDIT

Based on the 32/64-bit info, perhaps manually change the "<Platform>" in the .fsproj file.  (Right click the project, 'Unload Project', then right click again and 'Edit Whatever.fsproj', poke the XML to have 'x86' (rather than 'x64' or 'AnyCPU') as the Platform value, save, and right click project and 'Reload'.)  (Various F# bugs in Beta1 conspire to make the Platform/SolutionConfiguration-experience less than optimal.)

Comment: For those interested in what's happening in more detail:

http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnhar/archive/2008/02/25/xna-framework-on-64-bit-windows.aspx

Comment: See also stuff mentioning F# in http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/A/0/7A023209-096F-4F7D-B2BC-831ECC68FF5B/VS2010Beta1Readme.htm